# Is possible in Android remember in player time where it is stopped ?

Tags: android

Is possible in Android remember in player time where it is stopped ? I need to play mp3 in player and when user stops, or app goes to pause, I need to remember current state so user can play again from same time when starts again that file. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Don't know if this would be the best way to accomplish it, but couldn't you just write the time to SharedPreferences then onResume() just start playing the file from that location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `getCurrentPosition()` on the `MediaPlayer` when you wish to save off the position (e.g., `onPause()`). Write that to a persistent store (database, `SharedPreferences`, or other sort of file). Use `seekTo()` to return to that position later on as needed.